# Drupal, SQL Server and IIS7

Tags: php, sql-server, drupal, iis-7

Is there a SQL Server Provider for Drupal? I know that there is a SQL Server Client for PHP in beta and I wonder whether it would be hard to change the database provider to point to SQL Server instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal core only officially supports MySQL and PostgreSQL as database providers for Drupal 6, with work being done to support SQLite for Drupal 7.

The best resource I could find was this item (http://drupal.org/node/74308) in the issue queue, but it hasn't had activity in a few months.  There are a few patches posted with database layer files, but you will have to thoroughly test them for your use.

There were a couple postings on groups.drupal.org about using SQL Server for sites as well that may be worth checking out: http://groups.drupal.org/taxonomy/term/844.

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal 6 does not support SQL Server](http://drupal.org/requirements#database). Drupal 7's [new database layer](http://groups.drupal.org/node/15090) will be based on [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). While [PDO doesn't yet work directly with SQL Server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/705e664b-a422-4134-879a-6e4ea3413a05), both PDO and SQL Server work with [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php). So, in theory, you'll be able to use SQL Server with Drupal 7. How that works in practice remains to be seen.